# How to log a custom field to AWS CloudWatch to allow filtering from Insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an ECS Task Definition with the following Cloud Formation configuration:

```
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Ref Name
              awslogs-datetime-format: '%d %b %Y %H:%M'
```

I would like the logs I send to CloudWatch to include HostName as a filterable field that would appear in the AWS Insights console.

The application is using dotnet core 2.2.  I also have configuration in it as follows:

```
  "AWS.Logging": {
    "Region": "us-east-1",
    "LogGroup": "one-hub-stack-qa",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
```

How can I filter on a custom field @HostName in AWS Insights?  Note: this question might also require an understanding of how to actually send HostName to CloudWatch.

Answer (score -2):

You can collect custom metrics via StatD in cloudwatch, See more details here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-custom-metrics-statsd.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP is asking about how to add custom fields to log messages in CloudWatch